# GWT Developer plugin for Chrome and Internet Explorer - error preventing installation

Tags: java, internet-explorer, google-chrome, gwt

I am trying to install the GWT Developer plugin for Chrome (Version 34.0.1847.131 m) and I get the following error "This application is not supported on this computer. Installation has been disabled. The following problems are detected:" and "NPAPI plugin is required by this app". Is there a way around this?

I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package as suggested by one answer.

I am also trying to run in Explorer (version 11) and it requires me to download the GWT Developer plugin for Firefox. Which then requires content to be opened in a new window. I then elect to open "gwt-dev-plugin.xpi". When it finishes downloading it requests me to save it (if I open it it just download again). Is there a way around this?

I am running on Windows 8.1.

Comment: It is time for moving to SuperDevMode! :D

Comment: Hi apanizo, sorry I ignored your comment. I did not understand what it meant. I will investigate this further. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I am also trying to run in Explorer (version 11) and it requires me to download the GWT Developer plugin for Firefox.

To avoid that, open IE11 dev tools and under the "Emulation" menu change the "Document mode" from "Edge" to "10". The page should refresh and from there you should be able to install the GWT plugin for IE.

[image]

Once it's installed you can fall back to the "Edge" document mode.

Worked for me.

But as @apanizo said, I'd use the Super Dev Mode if possible. The dev mode is already not supported anymore in the latest firefox and it is going to be the same for the upcoming Chrome 35. No clue about IE though.

Comment: Hi Alexis, My heart felt gratitude for this. I did notice the comment by @apanizo but did not understand what it meant. I will now investigate further. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi Alexis, Every now and then this issue reappears with IE. I found that if I cut and past the url into IE or start it from the url drop down then it works. Chrome works but is really, really slow! Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Thanks for the work around. While Super Dev Mode is the newest thing, as a Java developer debugging Java code in the browser is counter intuitive, a browser's tools are not as powerful as Eclipse et. al. Hopefully the GWT team will give us this functionality back, until then I'll be using this workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Enable the GWT Developer Plugin in Chrome.

Check for other plugin that is installed on Chrome.

[image]

[image]

Click on `plugins for other systems` to get more GWT Developer plugins.

Here is the URL for [GWT missing-plugin](http://www.gwtproject.org/missing-plugin/).

[image]

[image]

Click on required GWT plugin and simply click on `save` button as shown below for IE9.

[image]

Comment: Hi Braj, I found this for Chrome "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/l5dj2xxPBuk". It seems there is an issue with Chrome in Windows 8. I have installed the Explorer plugin by selecting "Plugins for other systems", selecting the Explorer plugin, save and then run. However, when I try to run my application I get the same yellow popup requiring me to install the plugin. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 3):

This might be useful for you:

1. Create shortcut Chrome to desktop.
2. Right click to shortcut and choose properties.
3. Click to Compatibility tab
4. Inside Compatibility mode check "Run this compatibility mode for:" and choose Window 7.
5. Apply and Ok.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7778

Comment: Hi apanizo, Yes this worked. Thank you very much. Although it is very slow. I had two warnings in relation to a long running script, each of which I opted to wait for, before the page loaded. Loading of each subsequent page is also very slow. Now that the plugin is installed I will try reverting back to Win8 mode. Once again, thank you very much for your help. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to think Agile, here's what I adopted as a solution:

superDevMode is not practical, it takes forever to compile each time on my i7 with 8Gb of memory.

The solution I adopted is that I'm using FF for developement and I validate everything is fine only after GWT compiling on chrome (once in a while for the pauses).

Seriously I didn't see the point of having dev mode working on all browsers. In addition it runs curiously faster on FF than on Chrome (under windows). For Ubuntu (actually) I had to downgrade my FF to the version 24 to have it work (but since it's only a dev machine it doesn't bother me)

p.s: superDevMode might compile faster if optimized, hoestly I didn't try it: increasing the localWorkers could reduce compile time and make superDevMode a good solution, but I can't tell you; I didn't try that: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#localWorkers

Comment: You can find more on compile options here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html