# Unable to install GWT Developer Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I started learning GWT and wrote a sample app in Eclipse. I then said "Run on server". It gave me a URL to open and I opened that in Chrome. I saw a prompt asking me to install the GWT Developer Plugin and gave me a [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gwt-developer-plugin/jpjpnpmbddbjkfaccnmhnkdgjideieim). But I don't see any button to "Install". Is this some cruel joke from Google? What am I supposed to do now? How do I run the app? Eclipse only gives me this link which in turn gives me a prompt to install the plugin which I can't. On Firefox, it says version 29 not supported. What the hell is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GWT Developer Plugin isn't compatible to Firefox 27+. So it simply doesn't work with your FF 29.
[The reason why it doesn't work anymore can be found in a post by Brian Slesinsky](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+BrianSlesinsky/posts/2ZsefAgkV8j).

You have several options of how to work in the future:

- Use FF 26 (this can cause potential security problems)
- [Use FF ESR version](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/) (currently based on FF 24) that is typically used by Companies
- [Use Super Dev Mode](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html)
- Use Dev Mode with another supported browser (e.g. Internet Explorer) and test FF with a compiled version of your application only.

Comment: And why have they killed CHROME SUPPORT?

Comment: Chrome in phasing out NPAPI support in favor of PPAPI and the GWT plugin is implemented on top of NPAPI.

Comment: So no hope for Chrome then?

Comment: I'd say more like no hope for Dev Mode. There's no support for it in new versions of Firefox either because of some removed APIs. The GWT team is now focusing on Super Dev Mode instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this URL for [Installing GWT Missing Plugin](http://www.gwtproject.org/missing-plugin/).

For more info have a look at my another post [GWT Developer plugin for Chrome and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487257/gwt-developer-plugin-for-chrome-and-internet-explorer-error-preventing-instala/23487772#23487772)

---

Click on `plugins for other systems` to get more GWT Developer plugins.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you gone through the link that I shared you? every step is described there.

Comment: There are other links as well. Why don't you read it carefully? and  Google Dev plugin is not supported above Firefox 26. There is a link download plugin for Chrome.

Comment: Your other answer has the missing URL link for which I showed you what  I see and instructions to install on IE. I don't see a download link for Chrome in your linked answer