# Debugging GWT on newer browsers

Tags: gwt

I am working on a GWT project right now. I have Firefox 30, and Chrome 35, but cannot seem to find the plugin for Dev mode on both these browsers. Do I need to download an older version of these browsers, or am I missing something?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135296/unable-to-install-gwt-developer-plugin?lq=1)

Comment: GWT Dev plugin is supported till Firefox version 26 and Don't use Chrome for development due to bug in chrome itself.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24136414/11026) for details. Essentially, the developer plugin is not supported on newer browsers, you must use "SuperDevMode" instead.